# Package name is corrupted while copying the class

Tags: java, javassist

I defined Point class like below.

```
package com.sample.app.model;

public class Point {
    public int x;
    public int y;

}
```

When I try to construct other class with Point class data, I seen package name is corrupted.

```
CtClass pointClass = classPool.getAndRename("com.sample.app.model.Point", "com.sample.app.model.MyPoint");
```

Generated MyPoint.class code looks like below.

```
package model;

public class MyPoint {
  public int x;

  public int y;
}
```

As you see above snippet, package name is given as model, instead of "com.sample.app.model".

Surprisingly, When I print the new class name, it prints the package name correctly.

```
Class<?> myPointClass = pointClass.toClass();

System.out.println(myPointClass.getName());
```

But When I decompile the class file using [Java decompiler](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2015/09/jd-java-decompiler.html), I see package name corruption.

Comment: Sounds more like a potential defect entry on the bug tracker of javaassist. Beyond that: probably the "in memory" representation of that class is correct ... but what gets written to disc is wrong.

Comment: is this your goal: How  changing a class name for defining a new class?

Comment: I want to construct new class from existing class content

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **getAndRename** method is not for your requirement.

From official documentation: http://www.javassist.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

**Changing a class name for defining a new class**

A new class can be defined as a copy of an existing class. The program below does that:

```
ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
CtClass cc = pool.get("Point");
cc.setName("Line");
```

Comment: setName rename the existing class, but I want other class with the same content of existing class.

Comment: Could you save the renamed class as another class?